# stdout from interactive subprocess is cut short

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

When using `subprocess.Popen` on a Windows interactive command-line program, and setting `stdout = PIPE` or `stdout = somefileobject`, the output will always be cut short, or truncated, as well as missing prompts and other text.

So my question is: How do I capture all of the output of the subprocess?

More Details below:

I am specifically trying to grab the output from `steamcmd`. Here are some code examples and outputs I've run through the Python environment in the terminal.

```
from subprocess import Popen
#This command opens steamcmd, logs in, and calls licenses_print. It dumps 
#all licenses available to the user, and then quits the program.
cmd = (['path to steamcmd', 'arg1', 'arg2',...])
Popen(cmd)
```

In this I didn't set `stdout` to anything, so it dumps all output into the terminal and I can see everything. It's about 70 lines of text. The last few lines will be this, which is what I expect, and I get this from running `steamcmd` directly.

```
License packageID 166844:
 - State   : Active( flags 0 ) - Purchased : Sat Jun  2 12:43:06 2018 in "US", Wallet
 - Apps    : 620980,  (1 in total)
 - Depots   : 620981,  (1 in total)
```

But the moment I try to pass this into a file, like below

```
f = open('path to file', 'w+')
Popen(cmd, stdout = f).wait()
f.close()
```

The output dumped to the file gets cut short, and the last few lines look like this

```
License packageID 100123:
 - State   : Active( flags 512 ) - Purchased : Sat Jun 10 19:34:14 2017 in "US", Complimentary
 - Apps    : 459860,  (1 in total)
 - Depots   : 4598
```

You can see it didn't make it to package 166844, and it stops in the middle of the line "- Depots   : 459861,  (1 in total)"

I have read that PIPE has a size limit and causes it to hang, but it never has hung for me, the output isn't nearly big enough, but I tried outputting straight to the file anyways and it hasn't worked. I've tried using `check_output`, `getoutput`, but I assume they use the same thing under the hood anyways.

So again, my question again is: How do I capture all the output from the subprocess?

Edit 1: I've tried reading it out line by line, but it still cuts at the same place. I've tried Powershell and Windows Command Prompt. I tried this same thing on Linux Mint, with the Linux build of Steamcmd. On Linux I was able to capture all the output from the subprocess and store it in the file. So this seems like it may not be a python issue, but a Windows, or Windows cli issue that is causing it to not capture all the output. I tell it to wait, send it to PIPE instead of a file, it will always cut it short. Somewhere the last of the output gets dropped before making to my file.

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: Are you ever closing that file?

Comment: Yes, sorry i didn't put that but i do close the file. Ive done Popen(cmd,f).wait()  and then closed as well. And it hasn't worked. My question is why is it being cut off when i dump the output to a file, and how to make it so it doesn't?

Comment: I have experienced this same problem with Java, actually with SteamCMD as well.  I found that I had to use a WinPty library to get all of the output, and then had to filter the ANSI command codes that colored the output.

Comment: I have looked into WinPty for Python. I found one module, but it appears to be outdated, and not functional for Python 3.

Comment: Try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` and `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Comment: I added `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` and `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` and it didn't make a difference to the file output. But when `stdout = None` it provided one extra line at the bottom. `CWorkThreadPool::~CWorkThreadPool: work processing queue not empty: 2 items discarded.`

Comment: Why are you opening with `w+`?

Comment: My understanding was `w` meant is would open for writing, and over write anything in there, and the `+` meant it would create the file if it didn't exist. However looking into it again, the `+` doesn't appear to be needed.

Comment: @BeezerB: The `+` allows reading and writing on one open file.  `r+` (called “update”) does the same but preserves any existing contents.  And please use `@` in replies; I saw this only by chance.